# How to send post to laravel api from python?

Tags: python, laravel, python-requests

This is my python request code.

```py
url = "https://test.com/"
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
xsrf_token = r.cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN")

headers = {
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN':xsrf_token
}

data = {"account": "O_O@gmail.com", "password": "123123"}
r = requests.post(url+'/app/get/users', verify=False, data = data, headers=headers)
```

In laravel log, I got

> [2019-12-27 16:09:14] local.ERROR: The payload is invalid. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException(code: 0): The payload is invalid. at /var/www/html/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php:195)
>   [stacktrace]

Have any method to solve that? Thanks.

Comment: Is laravel API bug-free or well-documented to figure out what is `valid payload`? And what is the result of your python code? I suppose response has code `400 Bad request`. So only you can investigate it and fix the problem for now.

Comment: The exception *could* mean the `xsrf_token` is wrong. Cookies are encrypted in laravel so you can't really get the cookie directly. You can try scraping the response body for the csrf token instead (which is unencrypted) and passing it in in the `X-CSRF-TOKEN`. I am unfamiliar with python so don't know how you'd do that. However you need to ensure you are sending the unmodified cookies back otherwise you will lose the session information for which that particular token is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't solve the issue with a static xsrf alone since it's doing its job **preventing Cross Site Request Forging** wich is exactly what you're doing in that piece of code.

To use a route as an API, the laravel installation needs to be configured that way, so, if needed, a stateless way of authentification is used (jwt for example) instead of the session with xsrf token for post methods.

Basicly if it's not configured to be used as an API, you will not be able to use it as an API.

Comment: This code is not cross-site request forging. The request is not done cross site. Cross-site usually requires a user to go to site A and site A performing requests on behalf of user to site B, in this case the requests coming from site A **on behalf of the user** to site B are cross-site requests. In this case the "user" is performing requests directly, it just so happens the user is a python script

Comment: @apokryfos You're right, this is just request forging, the first step for cross site request forging. How do you think he got the XSRF TOKEN, with his code ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should not think like postman test post, thanks good answer, @N69S, thanks every comment.